# Add source link URL to web scraped data in R

Tags: r, web, screen-scraping

I have links that I need to scrape.

How can I add these links addresses to the scraped data as variable or just append?

```
links
for (i in links)
    {
      url<- (i)
      SC <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes ("NODES") %>% html_text ()
      Data<-rbind(SC)
    }
```

and I get the data like (for instance)

```
1. "name"
2. "price"
3. "date"
```

How can I add the 4th attribute as link URL

```
1. "name"
2. "price"
3. "date"
4. "source link address"
```

Or in another column?
Thank you

Comment: Instead of this loop try `Data <- lapply(links, function(x) {
    cbind(rbind(read_html(url) %>% html_nodes ("NODES") %>% html_text ()),x)
})` and `df <- do.call(rbind, Data)`

Comment: with this one I get i times of the same row and only one (I think the last) link address in the end

Comment: Can you provide some of the links

Comment: for instance
http://www.mothercare.com/christmas/gifts-for-babies/?q=christmas%27
http://www.mothercare.com/christmas/gifts-for-mums-and-mums-to-be/?q=christmas%27
http://www.mothercare.com/christmas/christmas-clothing/?q=christmas%27

and corresponding pages...

**I have a list of 12 such links and need to scrape data and put the links with them (these group of 12 items are from this page and so on)**

Comment: Data <- lapply (links, function(x) { rbind(cbind(read_html(curl(links, handle = new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))) %>% html_nodes (".date .price .name") %>% html_text ()), x) })
df <- do.call(rbind, Data)

**NOW I GET ONLY LINKS. I am using curl due to website specificity**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

links <- c("http://www.mothercare.com/christmas/gifts-for-babies/?q=christmas%27", 
           "http://www.mothercare.com/christmas/christmas-clothing/?q=christmas%27")

Data <- lapply(links, function(x){

  h <- read_html(x)
  items <- h %>% html_nodes(".m-title_link") %>% html_text %>% gsub("\\n", "", .)
  price <- h %>% html_nodes(".m-sales_price") %>% html_text %>% gsub("\\n", "", .)
  urls <- h %>% html_nodes(".m-title_link") %>% xml_attr("href") %>% 
          paste0("http://www.mothercare.com", .)
  data.frame(Name=items, Price=price, Link=x, Urls=urls)

})

Data <- do.call(rbind, Data)

View(Data)
```

Comment: Also how to get all the links of the items in these pages?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You should read the `rvest` and `xml2` packages

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you